# different htaccess between 2 environments (xamp)

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment

I have 2 environments:
'prod' and 'test'

The 'prod' env. is on the /site directory, himself on the root of the website

```
http://wwww.exemple.com/site/index.php
```

The 'test' env. is not on the root website:

```
http://wwww.exemple-test.com/wwww.exemple.com/site/index.php
```

I would like to install GIT and so .htaccess must be the same on the 2 env.

On 'prod' env, htaccess must look that:

- On the root:

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ site/index.php [NC,L]
  ```
- On the /site directory

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
  ```

On 'test' env, htaccess must look that

- On the /wwww.exemple.com/ directory

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ site/index.php [NC,L]
  ```
- On the /wwww.exemple.com/site directory

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
  ```

But it doesn't work. Why?

And what about css/js/... which are on /static dir, 
    (for example, with jquery)

```
http://wwww.exemple.com/site/static/js/jquery.js 
http://wwww.exemple-test.com/wwww.exemple.com/site/static/js/jquery.js
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is almost always a bad description. What do you expect? And what does happen instead? And how is this related to `git`?

Comment: Why so extremely complicated? Why not use a simple setup with two separate virtual hosts, one for prod, one for test? That way you have two separate configurations for the http hosts where you can do whatever is required for each environment separately. And only the things common go into a dynamic configuration file (which, btw, you should try to avoid all together, you should prefer the http host configuration anyway).

Comment: Olaf :"a bad description", yes, but it's the report after 1 day of testing. If i change, i don't fall on the good directory, or the good file, or static files are not taken/visible.
Related to git is that htaccess must be the same for the 2 env. (I would like not to 'gitignore' this file)
Arkascha :why so complicated ? I'm new in an agency, and although i did what you say before, it's not the way this agency works. (and before changing them...)

Answer (score 0):

Two virtual hosts would certainly be a lot cleaner, and easier, and all it would 'cost' you is a sub-domain name.

For my own project(s) I use a .htaccess file in development, but in the production configuration - I explicitly do not read that file, and instead have the `RewriteCond` etc, as part of the `<VirtualHost ...>` configuration. That also gives a small speed boost in production.